# Допустимо ли использование глаголов совершенного и несовершенного вида в одном перечислении?

Tags: стилистика, глаголы

Например:
Тенденция к действию: преодолеть препятствие на пути к достижению цели, восстановить справедливость, обвинять, нападать.